# javascript while loop

Tags: loops, while-loop

```
<input type="button" onclick=openAPage()></>
```

i have a button

```
function openAPage() {
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var myWin = window.open("http://www.sabah.com.tr","_blank")
var endTime = new Date().getTime();
var timeTaken = endTime-startTime;
myWin.close()

document.write("<br>button pressed@</br>")
document.write(new Date(startTime));
document.write("<br>page loaded@</br>")
document.write(new Date(endTime));
document.write("<br>time taken</br>")
document.write(timeTaken);   
}
```

and have a function

i want to call this function every 5 minutes? is it possible?

Comment: 5 minutes after they click the button ? or from when the page loads ? also i assume that the `</>` is a typo and you mean to self-close the input like `<input type="button" onclick="openAPage()" />` (*wrap the code in " as well*)

Comment: no i will press the button one time and every 5 mins later i want to call openApage function

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval( function(){

   openAPage();

}, 5*60*1000);
```

and setTimeout does it once.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy with jQuery.

```
window.setInterval(openAPage, 60*5*1000);
```

Comment: You could do it above the function openAPage. If you want to test it, then I would lower 60*5*1000 to 5000 (5 sec) to see if it works.

Comment: doesnt work unfortnately     <input type="button" onclick=openAPage()></>   will this be same?

Comment: Does the function openAPage work at all? Try to write another function test which does: alert("test"); and see if the setInterval works on that function.

Answer (score 0):

var timer = setInterval( openAPage, 60*5*1000);